# curl command causing indentation error in bitbucket CI/CD pipeline YAML

Tags: yaml, syntax-error, bitbucket, cloudflare

I am trying to add a `curl` command to my CI/CD YAML on bitbucket when I deploy to production. The `curl` command sends a POST request to the CloudFlare API to purge the cache. The command includes `-H` variables as necessary HTTP headers. This is causing an indentation error on bitbucket so that I can't commit my changes and I'm not sure why. I am not familiar with the YAML syntax and how I should fix this issue.

bitbucket-pipelines.YAML

```
image: python:3.7.4

clone:
 depth: full

pipelines:
   default:
     - step:
        caches:
          - pip
        script:
          - echo "nothing"
   branches:
      prod:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Staging
          deployment: staging
          script: #staging script
           - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_STAGING_APP_NAME.git HEAD:master --force
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          deployment: production
          trigger: manual
          script: #production script
           - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD:master --force
           - "curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$ZONE\purge_cache" -H "X-Auth-Email: $CLOUDFLARE_AUTH_EMAIL" \
          -H "X-Auth-Key: $CLOUDFLARE_AUTH_KEY" \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"purge_everything":true}'"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes within the command. Also, the `-H` continuation lines are not indented far enough – they must be indented more than the list item indicator on the line where the scalar starts.

A better way to do this would be to use a folded block scalar:

```
        - >-
          curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$ZONE\purge_cache"
          -H "X-Auth-Email: $CLOUDFLARE_AUTH_EMAIL"
          -H "X-Auth-Key: $CLOUDFLARE_AUTH_KEY"
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"purge_everything":true}'
```

Folded block scalars fold newlines into spaces and do not process any special characters, so you don't need to escape anything (and in fact, there are no escape sequences in block scalars).